# Pass Javascript Variable to Another Function via Onclick

Tags: javascript

JavaScript novice here....I need to call a JavaScript function that is passed two variables.  I then need those 2 variables to be passed to another function via an onClick event. Here is the general idea:

```
function FirstFunction(var1, var2) {
    // Using console.log to verify passed variables
    console.log(uid);
    console.log(accessToken); 
    $('#dialog-message').html('<div><button onclick="SecondFunction(var1, var2)">Submit</button></div>');
};

function SecondFunction(var1, var2) {
    // Using console.log to verify passed variables
    console.log(uid);
    console.log(accessToken); 
};
```

I am unable to see var1 & var2 in SecondFunction().  What's wrong here?

Comment: The inline click event handler will be evaluated in *global scope*, not inside the function scope. It look like you are using jQuery, so use it to create the DOM elements and bind the event handler. http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/, http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling. I am not well versed in jQuery so I am not certain how to do as you suggested - I did however solve part of my issue by declaring var1 & var2 as global variables and I can at least now see them in the SecondFunction call.  This is part of a Facebook JavaScript SDK issue - Which I've posted in a separate question if you think you can help.  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608444/fb-api-doesnt-completly-execute-when-called-from-another-function-call) - Thanks again.

Comment: That's why I added the links ;) But anyways, I added an answer, I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original comment:

> The inline click event handler will be evaluated in global scope, not inside the function scope. It look like you are using jQuery, so use it to [create the DOM elements](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements) and [bind the event handler](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics).

This way, you can avoid the whole problem (and don't have to use global variables):

```
function FirstFunction(var1, var2) {
    var $button = $('<button />', {
        click: function() {
            SecondFunction(var1, var2);
        },
        text: 'Submit'
    });

    $('<div />').append($button).appendTo('#dialog-message');
}
```

Because now the event handler is a closure with access to `var1` and `var2`.

Comment: Thanks again @FelixKling!!  This is what I needed to give me a jump start.  I did use the links you provided but it was pretty much Greek to me without a relevant example.  jQuery is new language for me but your answer helped greatly.  Now if I could the other issue with that function working now that it gets the variables I'll be all set!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#dialog-message').html('<div><button onclick="SecondFunction('+ var1 + ','+ var2+ ')">Submit</button></div>');
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? **Explain** your answer, and don't forget to mention that does only works if `var1` and `var2` are numbers, booleans or regular expressions..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#dialog-message').html('<div><button onclick="SecondFunction(' + var1 +', ' + var2  + ' )>Submit</button></div>');
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? **Explain** your answer, and don't forget to mention that does only works if `var1` and `var2` are numbers, booleans or regular expressions.